# plot two fields of struct in matlab using bar graphs

Tags: matlab

I have param as a matrix like below; I would like to plot param.num_av_BS and param.count_skip vs numerical number on x-axis. That is the two parameters as bar graphs on y axis and an integer on x-axis using matlab. please help.

param =

```
resources_user: [9 10 8 6 10 6 1 2 9 5]
           RSS: [10x1 double]
  resources_BS: [3 5 3 4 1 13 6 11 14 10 11 9 3 10 18 18]
      usr_c_bs: [7 5 5 0 3 11 6 9 11 13]
        x_user: [1.0020 8.0020 5.9920 9.0220 5.0020 5.0120 8.0300 3.0020 5.0080 9.0280]
        y_user: [5.9990 7.9950 7.0040 6.0030 2.9940 6.0070 1.0020 6.0080 6.0160 7.0080]
        x_base: [1 1 4 6 7 8.5000 1 1.5000 1.5000 5 4 6 8.5000 8.5000 4 5]
        y_base: [1 2 3.5000 4 7 1.5000 7 9 5 1 7 9 8.5000 4 5 1]
           UID: 10
         c_rss: [0.3400 0.4900 0.0500 0.4700 0.4000 0.4900 0.4600 0.0400 0.4000 0.1300]
        sel_bs: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
        RSS_av: [-80 -73 -65 -78 -76 -65 -71 -75 -65 -68]
     num_av_BS: [6 4 7 5 7 9 4 8 9 4]
    count_skip: [6 3 2 5 2 6 1 2 8 2]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
>> bar([param.count_skip' param.num_av_BS'])
```

[image]